# Scala/Akka websocket server library

Tags: scala, websocket, akka

I need a websocket server in order to be able to deliver server side events to my web application. Is there any library to build a websocket server using scala, preferably akka?

Comment: server side events is not the same as websockets, please rephrase your question. SSE or Websockets? I guess you could start out with a Play example (which uses Akka underneath) that you can find here: https://github.com/matthiasn/sse-chat . A websockets example here: https://github.com/playframework/playframework/tree/master/samples/scala/websocket-chat

Comment: I thought that it is not necessary to distinguish since I can build SSEs using websockets, I am right?

Comment: The question makes sense "Is there any library to build a websocket server using scala, preferably akka?", but the first sentence does not for the reason that the first commenter points out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Play Framework (http://www.playframework.com/) has strong support for web sockets (http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.2/ScalaWebSockets). Play also plays well with Akka (http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.2/ScalaAkka).

Note: SSEs are not WebSockets. WebSockets are for duplex communication between server and client while SSEs are only server to client. Both can be done in Play. See http://matthiasnehlsen.com/blog/2013/05/01/server-sent-events-vs-websockets/ for an illustrative example.